# How to handle return values in the function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, return

I have this function:

```
function kontrola(){    
    var jmeno = self.document.forms.newPassForm.user.value;
    $.get("checkMail.php?mail="+jmeno, function(data){ 
        if(data=='1'){
            alert('Tento uživatel v databázi neexistuje!');
            return false;
        }else return true;          
    }); 
}
```

My problem now is, that alert is not displaying (value for data variable is passed ok). If I add return false; at the end of the function, the alert is displayed, but if condition isnt fullfilled, I can´t send data from the form. Do you have any solution for this?

Comment: }else return true; ... is incorrect ... }else{ return true;}

Comment: Are you calling your function `onsubmit` from your form?

Comment: I checked http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/ and the function looks correct without having tested it. It may only be the syntax error on the else.

Comment: While not necessarily good style I think this is actually valid see this http://jsfiddle.net/MN86d/11/

Answer (score 2):

`return` does not do the same thing in a jQuery callback as it would in a normal function.

jQuery views `return true;` as **continue** (and assumes that you just wanted to skip to the next object in the jQuery object's set) and `return false;` as **break** (and assumes you just want to break out of the current iteration). `return false` when used in some event handlers will also prevent the default event behavior, but it is not the recommended approach to do that.

A better way to accomplish getting the return value would be to "split" your calling function with a callback that you inject into the `get` call.

```
function kontrola(callback){    
 var jmeno = self.document.forms.newPassForm.user.value;
 $.get("checkMail.php?mail="+jmeno, function(data){ 
    if(data=='1'){
        alert('Tento uživatel v databázi neexistuje!');
        callback(false);
    }else{ callback(true); }     
 });
}

function someCaller(){
 var someWork = 1 + 2;
 //split the rest of this call function to be done inside of the callback
 kontrola(function(result){
  var boolResult = result;
  if( boolResult ){
   //do more work
  }else{
   //handle false case
  }
 });
}
```

**edit**

Since this is attached to a submit button, I would suggest sending the submit element with the event

```
onsubmit = return "kontrola(this);"
```

For the reason that you are going to submit at a later time if successful

```
function kontrola(submitElement){    
 var jmeno = self.document.forms.newPassForm.user.value;
 $.get("checkMail.php?mail="+jmeno, function(data){ 
  if(data=='1'){
    alert('Tento uživatel v databázi neexistuje!');
  }else{ submitElement.submit(); }     
 });
 return false;
}
```

Comment: Im a bit confused....where do I call someCaller(); ? Im not that interested in getting the return value - Im not working with it anywhere...I just need to stay on the page after the alert window is closed or to continue to the next page if there was no alert window and the form submit button has been clicked. I only thought that I can achieve this by "playing" with return...

Comment: @MichalSirůček - I take it this is attached to a submit event then? Can you show how that is set up so I can make a better example.

Comment: Sorry, should have write that in my question. Here it is - I just have set onSubmit: onSubmit="return kontrola();". When I click on submit button, the kontrola() function is called, then via ajax I call checkMail.php, where I check e-mail address, if it exists in DB or not. If it exists, alert window appears. If it doesn´t "nothing" happens and form data are passed to further processing.

Comment: @MichalSirůček - See edit. Basically you will just default return false and then if the ajax test passes you call submit on the element manually and it submits the form.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense! But it still doesn´t work...I think that when I call the sumbit - self.document.forms.newPassForm.newPassSubmit.submit(); , that function kontrola(); is called again and it won´t go to the step, when form data are processed.

Comment: I get it to work...I had to call only newPassSubmit.submit(); ...but now instead of processing the data, it just returns me to the index.php. I process the data in if(isset($_POST['newPassSubmit'])){} block...can be problem here? Maybe there is no POST set if I submit the form manually? Is there any way around?

Comment: I tried to add $.post( "index.html",{ newPassSubmit: "true"}); behind the submit();, but to no result :(

Answer (score 0):

If you `data` variable is an integer, you will want `data===1` without those currently present single quotes (which compares to a string, which will always fail when comparing to a number).

Comment: No no, data variable is string.